Keycloak Nginx Integration Issue
I'm running nginx in port 1001. I'm trying to run the keycloak under nginx using reverse proxy. The below is nginx config changes.
server {
                listen 1001;
                server_name _;
                root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location ~ /auth {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        }

Below is the command I ran to start the keycloak server.
nohup ./kc.sh start-dev --hostname localhost:1001 --http-relative-path /auth &

I'm getting the welcome page. If I click Administration console, I'm getting the following error
The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'frame-src' contains an invalid source: 'http://localhost:1001:1001'
If I run with below command by removing 1001. I'm able to see the login page which I'm expecting.
nohup ./kc.sh start-dev --hostname localhost --http-relative-path /auth &

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong in the above scenario. Thanks in advance :)
I'm expecting login page instead I'm getting below error in console.
The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'frame-src' contains an invalid source: 'http://localhost:1001:1001'

I have resolved myself with below run command to run the keycloak behind proxy server. Issue resolved by mentioning hostname and port seperately.
nohup ./kc.sh --verbose start-dev --proxy edge --hostname localhost --hostname-port 1001 --http-relative-path /auth --hostname-strict false --hostname-strict-https false --http-enabled true --log-level=debug &
